# Why are my arms bending with a bone instead of following the bone exactly

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, bones, bone.constraints

I am having major problems rigging my model

The right arm on the model is bending instead of staying straight like the left arm

[image: right arm]

[image: Left Arm]

Here is the model
[image]

Comment: Hello maybe you need to recalculate the normals before parenting, or please share your file

Comment: @moonboots I added the file at the bottom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see the normals of the right arm are inverted, it will fail the parentage, you need to select all and recalculate in *Edit* mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>), then parent again and it will work:

[image]